# Extending private key validity period for code signing SSL certificate?

Tags: windows, ssl, ssl-certificate, code-signing, mmc

I have bought a 2 years Code signing ssl certificate, I am following this guide: https://www.godaddy.com/help/windows-generate-csr-for-code-or-driver-signing-certificate-7282 in order to create a CSR + private key.

The problem is that the generated private key validity period is 1 year and I have bought a certificate for 2 years.
Does it mean that after 1 year, i will have to re-key in order to code sign my application?

If so - how can I extend the validity period of the private key that is generated during the CSR request? (I am using Windows 10 MMC Certificate Snap-in).

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I doubt it. Nobody else can see your private key or its attributes. More likely you can't reuse that private key for another CSR after one year. All the outside world can see is your 2-year certificate.

Comment: But the application binary is being code signed also by the private key. so the question is if it will be possible to code sign it also after 1 year (when the private key was expired).

Comment: I imagine you can't use the key for signing CSRs or code after it expires.